# Organizing App Version, iDevice OS & Device

Tags: ios, swift, email

Below is a great way to organize all of the following information from **one source**:

1. App Version
2. iPhone OS
3. Device

I needed this information so that I can email them as part of my apps feedback feature.

Comment: That's how you have to do it though. You'll have to go through UIDevice and then the info plist.

Comment: Look at the answer below.

Comment: ... which does exactly what I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let infoDict = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary
let current = UIDevice.currentDevice()
let payload = [ "BundleID" : infoDict!["CFBundleIdentifier"]!,
    "AppVersion" : infoDict!["CFBundleShortVersionString"]!,
    "BundleVersion" : infoDict!["CFBundleVersion"]!,
    "DeviceName" : current.name,
    "DeviceModel" : current.model,
    "SystemName" : current.systemName,
    "SystemVersion" : current.systemVersion ]
```

To combine that into one string:

```
let string = payload.keys.array.reduce("", combine: { (input, key) -> String in
        return "\(input)\r\n\(key): \(payload[key])"
    })
```

Comment: Great implementation of the info. Thanks

Comment: To get it into my email I used messageBody = "Hello Chronic Team, " + (NSString(format: "%@", payload) as String)

Comment: Do you know how to format it so that each element is on a line by itself? My idea is to add elements between them that are "\n" or call each element separately and add "<div>"

Comment: Impressive coding. Though the above does make them optional again. Also I didn't want them all combined into one string but rather each element to be one line in my email message body.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand fully what is your problem with that code

Comment: No worries. the above prints out a a single string with all the content of the dictionary. What I'm looking to achieve is to have each element of that dictionary as a line in my email body

Comment: The above works but it adds the whole dictionary as ONE string. I'm looking to add each element as a line in my email body. so basically a way to separate each element into a line so when I put it into my messege body  string, it will show up separated

Comment: If you mail is HTML then maybe `return "\(input)</br>(key): \(payload[key])"` will work?

Comment: Great, I got it! return "\(input)\r\n\(key): \(payload[key]!)</br>"

Answer (score 1):

You're really just talking about 3 strings.

For #2 and #3 you just need:

```
NSString *osVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

NSUUID *deviceID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
```

Note that the UUID you get back is specific to your company bundle ID and the device ID.  It isn't the actual device ID, but it will give you the same ID across multiple apps from the same vendor on the same device.

[Apple UIDevice reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDevice)